# Opengl: Making texture background transparent by picking a color

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a picture of a tree in OpenGL as a 2D texture. I want to remove the background (skyblue) or rather make that part transparent. How can I do this in the fragment shader. The closest I came up with is removing the pixels of the texture that are above a threshold value. For e.g

```
#version 330
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D theTexture;

void main()
{
  vec4 texel = texture(theTexture, texCoord);
  if(texel.b < threshold)
     discard;
  outColor = texel;
```

}

Comment: And what's wrong with that solution?

Comment: This will not work as you describe it, because it discards pixels that are ***below*** a threshold value. As your question is written now, you just have to flip the sign in the comparison.